# need help for condition statement for keys in python

Tags: python

```
conn = pywbem.WBEMConnection(server_uri, (user, password),default_namespace='root/cimv2')
#server = pywbem.WBEMServer(conn)
#help(conn)
#print("Interop name:\n %s" % conn.interop_ns)
#print ("All namespaces:")
#for ns in conn.namespaces:
#  print(" %s" %ns)
ClassesToCheck = [
#  'OMC_SMASHFirmwareIdentity',
#  'CIM_Chassis',
#  'CIM_Memory',
  'CIM_Processor',
]

for className in ClassesToCheck:

  instance_list = conn.EnumerateInstances(className)
  print instance_list
  for instance in instance_list:
    if verbose:
       print
       print 'Instance of : %s' %className
       print '============================================================'
      # print 'instanceName = %s' %instance
       for key,value in instance.items():
          #if key in [ModelName,Stepping,EnabledProcessorCharacteristics,CPUStatus]:
```

instance.items has lot of keys and value, I want to print particular keys values only.
Need logic  for this

Comment: .... `print(instance[some_key])`?

Comment: Could you elaborate, what kind of keys values you want? What does instance.items() contain?

Comment: I believe the last commented out line is pretty much correct approach!

Comment: Like `if keys in ['foo','bar']: Do stuff and things`.

Comment: @UbdusSamad no, you should loop over the candidate keys, since `len(candidates) << len(the_dict)`

Comment: Or `for k in ['one', 'other', 'additional']: if k in instance: print('{0} = {1}'.format(k, instance[k]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could print a smaller dictionary:

```
for k, v in my_dict.items():
  if some_condition(k):
    print(k, ':', v)
```

or

```
print({ k: v for k, v in my_dict.items()
        if some_condition(k) })
```

If you have a fixed list of keys you want to print, iterate over them:

```
my_keys = [ 'ModelName', 'Stepping',
            'EnabledProcessorCharacteristics', 'CPUStatus']

for k in my_keys:
  print(k, ':', my_dict[k])
```

or

```
print({ k: my_dict[k] for k in my_keys })
```

Comment: my_keys = [ 'ModelName', 'Stepping',
            'EnabledProcessorCharacteristics', 'CPUStatus']

for k in my_keys:
  print(k, ':', my_dict[k]) worked for me ..Thanks Alfe